# Accessing entry widget data creating using for loop for plotting purposes

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I have created this GUI, my app tries to collect several input float data from the user through two columns of entry widget and then storing the data to a list so that I can later be able to plot these data on a 2D plot. I have created a table of widgets consisting of a maximum of 20 rows that the user define them based on their data through combo box.

My question now is how I can access the data that the user has input to these entries and store them in a list so that I can plot them using `matplotlib`?

Please advise.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


window=Tk()
window.title ("xxxx")

wrapper2=LabelFrame(window,text='xxx Data')
wrapper2.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both",expand="yes",padx=10,pady=10)

###Table###

l4=tk.Label(wrapper2, text="Number Of Points")
l4.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)


Text_4=IntVar()
b1=ttk.Combobox(wrapper2,width=2,textvariable=Text_4,state='readonly')
b1["value"]=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
b1.grid(row=0,column=2)


l5=tk.Label(wrapper2, text="(Meters)")
l5.grid(row=1,column=1)

l6=tk.Label(wrapper2, text="Pre ")
l6.grid(row=1,column=2)

def table_generation():  
    
    rows=int(Text_4.get())
    X_Depth=[]
    Y_Pressure=[]
    
    
    entryvar=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    entryname=["ae","be","ce","de","ee","fe","ge","he","ie","je","ke","le","me","ne","oe","pe","qe","re","se","te","ue","ve","we","xe","ye","ze"]
    
    for i in range(rows):
        l4=tk.Label(wrapper2, text=i+1)
        l4.grid(row=i+2,column=0)
        
        for depth_col in range(0,1):
            entryvar[i]=DoubleVar()
            entryname[i] = Entry(wrapper2, text=entryvar[i])
            entryname[i].grid(row=i+2, column=depth_col+1)
            entryname[i].bind("<KeyRelease>",  X_Depth.append(entryvar[i].get()))
            X_Depth.append(entryname[i].get())
            
        for press_col in range(1,2):
            entryvar[i]=DoubleVar()
            entryname[i] = Entry(wrapper2, text=entryvar[i])
            entryname[i].grid(row=i+2, column=press_col+1)
            entryname[i].bind("<KeyRelease>",  Y_Pressure.append( entryvar[i].get()))
            Y_Pressure.append( entryname[i].get())     
      
       
    print(X_Depth)
    print(Y_Pressure) 
    
b1=Button(wrapper2, text='Generate',command=table_generation)
b1.grid(row=0,column=3) 

window.mainloop()
```

If I entered in the combobox widget a value of 5 for example a 5 rows will be generated and the user can enter the values.hovwever when a value is enterd to the entries the lists X_Depth and Y_Pressure dont update with the user input rather they remain showing 5 zeros as below.

`[0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0']`
`[0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0', 0.0, '0.0']`

Comment: When asking question  here, is often important to include code representing a [mre]. What's currently in your question is far from that in the sense that it import unused modules as well as one unrelated to question.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. If the question is about retrieving data from entries created in a loop, we don't need much more than that loop, a function where you've tried to retrieve the data, and enough extra code to make it all work.

Comment: Your code is already creating two lists, `X_Depth` and `Y_Pressure`, based on input from the `Entry` widgets — so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @martineau thanks for your replay. I have minimised the code. and explained it little farther. I have created the two lists, X_Depth and Y_Pressure to store the entry values from the user but for some reason they are always stuck at zero and never update to the user input.

Comment: Good job minimizing the code. Your `table_generation()` function should not _also_ be trying to retrieve information of the `Entry` widgets it creates. So, in addition to those widgets, you'll also need a create a separate `Button` attached to a different function to retrieve the information of these `Entry` widgets when the user has filled them in and clicked on this new button. This other function can also plot them or do whatever else you want with the information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use `matplotlib`, but the code below shows how to get the data from the user the way I think you want (and I suggested in a comment). You could easily change the newly added <kbd>Get Lists</kbd> button to plot data entered once you figure out how to do that part.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


window = Tk()
window.title("xxxx")

wrapper2 = LabelFrame(window,text='xxx Data')
wrapper2.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)

###Table###

l4=tk.Label(wrapper2, text="Number Of Points")
l4.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

Text_4 = IntVar()
b1 = ttk.Combobox(wrapper2, width=2, textvariable=Text_4, state='readonly')
b1["value"] = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
b1.grid(row=0, column=2)

l5 = tk.Label(wrapper2, text="(Meters)")
l5.grid(row=1, column=1)

l6 = tk.Label(wrapper2, text="Pre ")
l6.grid(row=1, column=2)

row_labels = []  # Global
depth_entries, depth_vars = [], []  # Global
pressure_entries, pressure_vars = [], []  # Global
btn_get = None
X_Depth, Y_Pressure = [], []

def table_generation():
    ''' Generate row widgets. '''

    global btn_get

    def destory_widgets(*widget_lists):  # Helper func.
        ''' Destroy and clear lists of widgets. '''
        for widget_list in widget_lists:
            for widget in widget_list:
                widget.destroy()
            widget_list.clear()

    if btn_get:
        btn_get.destroy()
        btn_get = None
    destory_widgets(row_labels, depth_entries, pressure_entries)

    for i in range(int(Text_4.get())):  # Create table of widgets.
        row_label= tk.Label(wrapper2, text=i+1)
        row_label.grid(row=i+2, column=0)
        row_labels.append(row_label)

        entryvar = DoubleVar()
        depth_vars.append(entryvar)
        entry = Entry(wrapper2, text=entryvar)
        entry.grid(row=i+2, column=1)
        depth_entries.append(entry)

        entryvar = DoubleVar()
        pressure_vars.append(entryvar)
        entry = Entry(wrapper2, text=entryvar)
        entry.grid(row=i+2, column=2)
        pressure_entries.append(entry)

    btn_get = Button(wrapper2, text='Get Lists', command=get_lists)
    btn_get.grid(row=i+3, column=0)


def get_lists():
    ''' Create lists from data in Entry widget vars. '''
    global X_Depth, Y_Pressure

    X_Depth.clear()
    Y_Pressure.clear()

    for depth, pressure in zip(depth_vars, pressure_vars):
        X_Depth.append(depth.get())
        Y_Pressure.append(pressure.get())

    print('X_Depth:', X_Depth)
    print('Y_Pressure:', Y_Pressure)

b1 = Button(wrapper2, text='Generate', command=table_generation)
b1.grid(row=0, column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot of it after selecting `5` in the combobox and clicking on the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button:

[image: screenshot of it running]